# How to add rows in middle of a table with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I've a table which has customers names along with the products they purchased with their prices. So there are multiple records for each customer. This table is simple 3 column table : name, product and price.

What I want to do is:

Put all records belonging to one customer together (I've done it) and just after these rows add one new extra row which would just show total price of all the products each customer has purchased. This row would have empty cell in name and product column. And would have total in price column.

**EDIT**

It's just a plain simple table without any class or ids. customer wise grouped Table is generated by php. So I've a table like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> name1 </td>
        <td> product1 </td>
        <td> 100 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> name1 </td>
        <td> product2 </td>
        <td> 200 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> name2 </td>
        <td> product3 </td>
        <td> 50 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> name2 </td>
        <td> product1 </td>
        <td> 100 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to convert this to :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> name1 </td>
        <td> product1 </td>
        <td> 100 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> name1 </td>
        <td> product2 </td>
        <td> 200 </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- New row -->
    <tr>
        <td>  </td>
        <td>  </td>
        <td> 300 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> name2 </td>
        <td> product3 </td>
        <td> 50 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> name2 </td>
        <td> product1 </td>
        <td> 100 </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- New row -->
    <tr>
        <td>  </td>
        <td>  </td>
        <td> 150 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How are you demarcating the rows for each customer?  A class?  IDs?  If you have something identifiable, it should be easy to get that row and modify the DOM after it.

Comment: Can you provide some HTML code? So that we can see which class names you give the elements etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using jQuery you can select all rows where the username is contained within one of it's descendant elements. I'm assuming usernames are unique.

```
$("tr:contains('" + username + "')")
```

Now, get the last one

```
$("tr:contains('" + username + "')").last()
```

And use the `after` function to insert your new row.

Comment: ok, I see the point. I can add class based on names and use your trick. But I think somehow I've to get list of all names first.

Answer (score 22):

```
var prize = 1 * 1;
    var newrow = $('<tr><td></td><td></td><td>' + prize + '</td></tr>');
    $('#rowid').after(newrow);
```

or

```
newrow.insertAfter('#rowid');
```

where `#rowid` is an id from a row you want to append a new line.

Comment: i used this answer. very helpful :) by the way, is there a way to animate the insert? :D