# How to group the table rows and add summary row above the group?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, group-by

I have an sql query that outputs a lot of information. What I need to do is group and summarize the information in the output table. Here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
name        val1    val2    val3    total   Run
some name    18       4       1       23    
 some name    5       4       1       23     2
 some name   13       8       2       23     1
other name    2       2       0        4     1
and name      2      42       1       45     1
```

The name that is coming in from the database can appear more then once. If it does I group those items together and add the Summary row above which would have the same name but also compute the totals:

- Val1 has to be added together
- Val2, Val3 has to be the same as the row with the largest value in RUN cell
- total value always stays the same.

There would be multiple occurrences of such grouping in the output table. 
I tried to google my question but the closest that I got to what I was looking for was this this: [How to add rows in middle of a table with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560613/how-to-add-rows-in-middle-of-a-table-with-jquery)
which is not really what I am doing.

I'm not sure if there is an sql command that I could use to do that, or if it can be done in php or with use of jquery. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you!

**Update:**

I have tried using GROUP BY in sql, but it gives me syntax error:

```
SELECT name, val1, val2, val2, run
FROM tableName
WHERE ... ORDER BY name DESC GROUP BY name
```

(don't mind the WHERE ... I actually have statements there).
The only time it actually grouped the query when I have two or three results in the query and all of the three have the same name. So I though the GROUP BY is not the option.

In the php I am storing the name into a variable and checking if the name the same or not. if it's not the same i add master class to the row, if not the class is child, which helps me group it. However I didn't figure out a way to add a summary row above.

I was thinking for every time the name changes add a blank row and use jquery to populate it after page is loaded, however, for one time occurances of a name I do not need the summary.

As for, Val3 in the summary row I have made changes above. Val3 will be the same as the val3 in the row with the largest run value. I think I was confused by my own example.

I hope this information is more helpful.

Comment: That's all well and good - but what have you tried to resolve your problem other than Google it? Do you have SQL, PHP or JQuery that you have started developing, but then got stuck? Show us something and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I can understand what you mean for val1 and val2, but I don't understand val3.  What are you subtracting and what are you subtracting it from?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have added the changes above.

Comment: Andres, you are correct, I have started developing the code but I am stuck. I'm not sure which way to approach the problem.

Comment: JJS, I have made updates in the question description, I hope that helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have to do something like this, I use multi-dimensional associative array with the top level keys being the highest level of grouping that I want to do.  In your case, that would be "name".

In each element of that array, there is another assoc array with a key for each value that I want to keep track of.  There is also a numbered sub-array that will contain each individual row that belongs in that grouping.

After I finish going through all the rows, I go through the resulting associative array and print the results.

For example:

```
<?php

/** Simulate of the results of your SQL query **/
$sql_result = array(
    array("name"=>"some name ", "val1"=>5,  "val2"=>4,  "val3"=>1,  "run" =>2),
    array("name"=>"some name ", "val1"=>13, "val2"=>8,  "val3"=>2,  "run" =>1),
    array("name"=>"other name", "val1"=>2,  "val2"=>2,  "val3"=>0,  "run" =>1),
    array("name"=>"and name",   "val1"=>2,  "val2"=>42, "val3"=>1,  "run" =>1)
);

/** Add each result to your assoc array **/
$names = array();
foreach($sql_result as $row) {
    $name = $row["name"];

    // Create a new assoc array for each different name
    if( !$names[$name] ) {
        $names[ $name ] = array(
            "name"      => $row["name"],
            "max_run"   => $row["run"],
            "val1"      => $row["val1"],
            "val2"      => $row["val2"],
            "val3"      => $row["val3"],
            "runs"      => array( $row )
        );
        continue;
    }

    // Update the necessary values for the highest "run" number
    if ($row["run"] > $names[ $name ]["max_run"]) {
         $names[ $name ]["max_run"] = $row["run"];
         $names[ $name ]["val2"]    = $row["val2"];
         $names[ $name ]["val3"]    = $row["val3"];
    }

    // Update the reset of the values
    $names[ $name ]["val1"]     += $row["val1"];
    $names[ $name ]["total"]    = $names[ $name ]["val1"] + $names[ $name ]["val2"] + $names[ $name ]["val3"];
    $names[ $name ]["runs"][]   = $row;

}

/** Print your results **/
foreach ($names as $name) {
    // Print your totals here like $name["total"], $name["val1"]
    echo  $name["name"]." ";
    echo  $name["val1"]." ";
    echo  $name["val2"]." ";
    echo  $name["val3"]." ";
    echo  $name["total"]."<br>";
    if ( count($name["runs"]) > 1 ) {
        foreach( $name["runs"] as $run ) {
            echo print_r($run)."<br>";
        }
    }
    echo "<hr>";
}

?>
```

This code is tested

Comment: Thank you JJS, this is a great approach. I was thinking about storing it into array as well, but didn't want to use up extra memory, since typically I would have at least a 100 results from the query. Do you think there is a way to avoid arrays? If not I will keep this implementation

Comment: Someone smarter than me might post something, but the only other way I can think of would be a few sub-queries in your SQL.  The assoc array approach is one I use a lot, and I haven't had problems even with waaay more than 100 results.

Comment: No problem.  If nobody posts anything better you can always thank me by clicking accept for the answer :)